# Dynamically Add New form fields pre-populated with user's input from another form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

Ok here's what I need to do---

Need to create a form - with two inputs: item and quantity
The user will input... There will be an add button like below.

```
<form id="form1">
   <input type="text id="item" name="" value="" placeholder="Item #">
   <input type="text id="quantity" name="" value="" placeholder="quantity">
   <input name="Add" type="button" class="add" value="add"/>
</form>
```

Here's the tricky part....

I need the input from form1 to create a new inputs in a separate form "form2" each time the user hits the add button... ie. they may add multiple items. Each item added needs to create a new input.

the name of the input below will be a combination of the value of #item and #quantity 
The user will then submit this form to the my shopping cart url

it will have to be formated as such

```
<form id="form2">
<input name="ADD_#itemvalue=#quantityvalue" value="" id="NewUcItem">
<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit"
</form>
```

Either needs to be done using jquery and/or velcoity

Thoughts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
-Nick

Answer (score 0):

Actually just made something similar to this a few days ago.  I edited it a bit so it should work for you.

```
<script>
function addForm(){
    $("#forms").append(
        "<form><input/>........</form>"
    );
}
</script>

<input name="Add" type="button" class="add" value="add" onclick="addForm();"/>
<div id="forms"></div>
```

Just edit the append part with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer :

```
(function($){ 
   $('.add').click(function(){ 
     var item = $('#item').val(); 
     var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); 
     $('<input name="ADD_'+item+'='+quantity+'" value="" ').insertBefore(#form_id2 input[name="submit"]'); 

   }):
})(jQuery);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @prabeen Going to give that a shot!